# Adding macro from one excel sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I'm working with a list of addresses in excel 365. I want to perform a reverse geocode function to produce addresses from the available longitude and latitude info. to do this I have found an excel addin https://github.com/gramener/geocode-excel , which I downloaded. you can see an example in the screenshot above. the formula which it introduces is:

```
=@NominatimReverseGeocode(B32,C32)
```

Now what I want to do is make this available in my main sheet so that I can use the NominatimReverseGeocode. I've gone to File - Options - File - Add Ins

[image]

But the function 'NominatimReverseGeocode' does not show up in my main sheet. How can I make this function available in my main sheet?

EDIT:

I renamed the file to geocode.xlam in powershell. Now I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: While I cannot open the file on github, I am assuming its a normal VBA function, which can just be added by pasting the code into the VBA editor.

Comment: That's an xlsm file, not an xlam. Save it as an xlam first.

Comment: please see edit

Comment: You cannot just rename an XLSM file to an XLAM file.  You have to open the XLSM file as an Excel worksheet, and then in Excel do a **Save As...** to an XLAM add-in.  Alternatively you could just copy the VBA code into your main workbook.

Comment: To give a more detailed answer, I would need to know: 1) Do you expect to have that function available in all your workbooks or just a specific one? 2) Should this function be available to other users of the workbook(s) or just you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intent is to make the Geocode functions available in all of your workbooks on your computer, do this:

1. Delete all previously saved `Geocode.xlsm` and `Geocode.xlam` files.
2. [Download Geocode.xlsm](https://github.com/gramener/geocode-excel).
3. Open it.
4. Go to `File` > `Save As`.
5. Change the file type from `Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)` to `Excel Add-in (*xlam)`.
6. Click `Save`.
7. Close all instances of Excel.
8. Open Excel. (i.e. just the Excel application, so not opening a workbook.)
9. You should be on the `Home` screen.
10. Go to `New` > `Blank workbook`.
11. In the ribbon go to `Developer` > `Excel Add-ins`.
12. Check `Geocode`.
13. Click `OK`.
14. Close all instances of Excel.
15. Open any Excel workbook or make a new blank workbook.
16. Put `=@NominatimReverseGeocode(51.5,-0.144)` in any cell.
17. This should resolve to the Buckingham Palace Garden.

If your intent is to just have the geocode functions in one specific workbook, let me know and I'll write up the steps for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need this code available for yourself and not other users by far the simplest way would be to create a personal macro workbook.

Create a workbook and save it as

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.xlsm

Copy the code from the GeoCode workbook into PERSONAL.xlsm.

PERSONAL.xlsm will autoload with Excel. Prefix your function call with the workbook name: `=PERSONAL.xlsm!@NominatimReverseGeocode(B32,C32)`