# Excel add in not activated

Tags: excel

[image]

I'm working with a list of addresses in excel 16. I want to perform a reverse geocode function to produce addresses from the available longitude and latitude info. to do this I have found an excel addin https://github.com/gramener/geocode-excel , which I downloaded. you can see an example in the screenshot above. the formula which it introduces is:

```
=@NominatimReverseGeocode(B32,C32)
```

Now what I want to do is make this available in my main sheet so that I can use the NominatimReverseGeocode.

I followed [Adding macro from one excel sheet to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68743476/adding-macro-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another) and got it working on my home computer. I'm now trying it on a work computer.

I emailed myself the geocode.xlam and added it via the developer ribbon:

[image]

However the functions do not show up in my sheet after closing and reopening. What am I doing wrong?

edit

[image]

edit2:

[image]

Comment: Is it actually an `xlam` file? The file on GitHub is an `xlsm`. Not the same.

Comment: I converted it to an xlam file. please see edit

Comment: If you open the VB Editor (Alt + F11), can you see the add-in in the Project Explorer (Ctrl +R)?

Comment: I don't see it - please see edit2

Comment: How exactly did you convert the xlsm to xlam? Also, do you see the add-in listed if you go to File > Options > Add-ins? Is it listed under Inactive Application Add-ins, or Disabled?

Comment: It looks active - see edit3. I followed the directions for the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68743476/adding-macro-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another. It worked on that computer. Now I emailed the add in to myself at work so I could install it

Comment: Try toggling the check mark next to Geocode off and on. If you can't see the add-in in the VB Editor, then it's not actually open/loaded. The steps in the linked thread to convert to an xlam are correct, so I'm not sure what's the culprit here.

Comment: The toggling seemed to work , when I open the vb editor you can see the geocode code now. - Thank you for walking me through that! If you want to enter an answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why, despite the add-in showing as active under File > Options > Add-ins, it hasn't actually been opened.

Try toggling the checkmark in the Excel Add-ins window off and on, which should (re)load the add-in.

As a check, you can open the VB Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>). You should see the add-in in the Project Explorer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).